# Why does the Azure DevOps REST API return no service endpoints?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the Azure Devops console I can see service connections.

I try to list them using the [Endpoints - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#serviceendpointactionfilter) API.

```bash
curl --url 'https://dev.azure.com/org1/proj1/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0'
```

The API gives me an empty list.

```json
{"count":0,"value":[]}
```

The Urban Canuk's [Invoking Azure DevOps Hidden REST API](http://www.bryancook.net/2022/01/invoking-azure-devops-hidden-rest-api.html) shares an awesome trick. Add `__rt=fps&__ver=2.0` to any console URL to get a JSON representation of all the data in the page.

I apply it to the service connections console like this:

```bash
curl --url 'https://dev.azure.com/org1/proj1/_settings/adminservices?__rt=fps&__ver=2.0' \
| jq -c '
.fps.dataProviders
.data["ms.vss-distributed-task.resources-hub-core-data-provider"]
.resourceItems[]
| {id, name}
```

And now I get a list of service connections.

```json
{"id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","name":"service-connection-a"}
{"id":"bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb","name":"service-connection-b"}
{"id":"cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc","name":"service-connection-c"}
```

Am I missing something? Is the "hidden" REST API really the only way to do this?

Comment: What `api-version` are you providing?

Comment: @DanielMann Good question! If the request doesn't specify, what does it default to? I'll see whether I can find out when I am in front of my computer.

Comment: @DanielMann I specified a version in the example. I get the same behavior for all documented versions: `7.1-preview`, `7.0`, `6.0`. `5.0`. `4.1`.